# The Euler Characteristic for closed surfaces, disjoint discs and boundaries

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

Show that if $S$ is a surface with boundary obtained by removing the interiors of $n$ disjoint closed discs from a closed surface $T$, then

(i) $\chi(S)=\chi(T)-n$

(ii) $S$ is orientable if and only if $T$ is orientable

I have just started a topology and geometry course and would greatly appreciate help with the question above. I believe this question may be using the Euler characteristic to solve it but I am unsure how to proceed. Thank you.

Comment: What's your definition of the Euler characteristic?

Comment: I believe it is X= V - E + F.  or one of the two other formulas for invariants given here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Relations_to_other_invariants. My apologies I should've clarified the formulas I was using.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

1) Triangulate $S$ in the following way : every disk $D$ will be triangulated with a single triangle, and triangulate the rest as you like. Now let's count : for every open disk removed, we simply lose 1 triangle, but we keep the same number of vertices/edges as they are on $\partial D$, i.e our Euler characteristic drops by 1 for every disk removed.

2) $S$ is orientable if and only if $S$ does contains a Moebius band : and removing or adding a disk does not changes the fact that $S$ contains a Moebius band.

Comment: Actually, one only removes the interior of the triangle. So for every disk removed, we lost zero edges, zero vertices, and one triangle; but this does not change the final conclusion.

Comment: @LeeMosher : right, I didn't read enough carefully the question. Thanks for your comment, I will edit my answer.